# how to implement a multi line output

Tags: textarea

Will someone kindly give me a hand. Suppose I have a text box and a button. If I type a number say 5 in the text box, I want the numbers 1 to 5 appear in the result text box, one number per line. How should be modifying. Thank you.

```
<html><head>
<title>Temp proj</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" 
 href = "temp.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<form name = "myform">
<input type = "text" name = "first" class = "mytext" size = "4"><br>
<input class = "button" name = "" value = "Enter" onclick = "enter()"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "result" class = "mytext" size = "4">
</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
 function enter(){
    first = parseInt(myform.first.value);
    myform.result.value = result;
 }
</script>
</head></html>
```